# how do you create new lines in a textfield?

Tags: django

I have a model with a TextField ("notes"), and I want to add strings to it using variables, but separate the variables with a new line (\n)

```
aaa = "variable 1"
bbb = "variable 2"
ccc = "variable 3"

model.objects.create(id=id, notes=aaa + '\n' + bbb + '\n' + ccc)
```

However, when I render the field in the template as `{{object.notes}}`, the variables aren't separated at all.

Comment: Render it as `{{ object.notes|linebreaksbr }}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n` represents newline in plain text, but you are asking about auto-creation of actual `p` and `br` HTML tags in the template layer. See the docs for [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) and [linebreaksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr).

Both of these will handle automatic insertion of linebreaks or paragraphs in your templates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use `< br />`  instead of `\n`